# How to use @Html.ValidationMessageFor for @Html.TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

The following works fine:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Residence.Rent, new { @class = "form-control"" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Residence.Rent, null, "span")
```

But the need is to send a list of objects to the controller. So I have tried this:

```
@for(int index = 0; index < Model.ResidencesList.Count; index++)
{
    @Html.TextBox("ResidencesList[" + index + "].Rent", ResidencesList[index].Rent, new { id="", @class = "form-control"" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor("ResidencesList[" + index + "].Rent", null, "span")
}
```

which renders the mark up as:

```
<input class="form-control" name="ResidencesList[0].Rent" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="ResidencesList[0].Rent" data-valmsg-replace="true">
   <span>undefined</span>
</span>
```

The validation doesn't fire on submit and also the message "undefined" shows when I select the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```
  @Html.TextBox("ResidencesList[" + index + "].Rent", ResidencesList[index].Rent, new { id="", @class = "form-control"" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor("ResidencesList[" + index + "].Rent", null, "span")
```

with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.ResidencesList[index].Rent, new {  @class = "form-control"})
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model=> model.ResidencesList[index].Rent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```